# Can't open multer uploaded files

Tags: image, express, multer

Hey has anybody had this problem. I am trying to upload images using multer (postman for sending them). Smaller files ~50Kb only appear as empty text/plain files, larger ~2.1Mb images get uploaded but their size differs (from original 2087736 bytes to 2023146) and I can't open them for PNG -> (Error not a png file) and in jpeg case -> (Not a JPEF file: starts with 0x8d 0x35).

On multer side I use some filtering and have some limits:

```
var photoUpload = multer({ storage: phtStorage, fileFilter: photoFilter, limits: limits }).single('file');
```

But they are nothing out of the ordinary

filter:

```
var photoFilter = function(req, file, cb) {

if (settings.acceptedPhotoTypes.indexOf(file.mimetype) !== -1)
    cb(null, true);
else
    cb('Invalid file type', false);
};
```

storage:

```
var phtStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        var path = settings.photoProcessingSrcDir;
        mkdirp(path, err => cb(err, path));
        cb(null, path);
    },
    filename   : function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, req.fileName.toString());
    }
});
```

limits:

```
var limits = { fileSize: 20000000 };
```

The only exotic thing I do is I pass the function `photoUpload` into another function, because I want to do some database validation before actually uploading.

```
router.post('/:catalogId/:storeId', protected, function(req, res, next) {

  if (f.type === 'photo') { 
    require('../helpers/files/post-photo')(photoUpload, req, res, next); 
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem. The Storage function was badly written:

```
var phtStorage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, cb) {
        var path = settings.photoProcessingSrcDir;
  ----> mkdirp(path, err => cb(err, path));
  ----> cb(null, path);
    },
    filename   : function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, req.fileName.toString());
    }
});
```

Both cb (callback function) are called and that caused multers inner stream creating function to create two streams. Which really messes up things...

Comment: isn't there a difference between the solution you provided and your question?